# MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail returns NO

Tags: objective-c, email, ios14, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I am trying to open the email app on ios device using MFMailComposeViewController. it works fine until iOS 12 but it fails for iOS 13 and 14. the error printed on the logs is `MFMailComposeViewController Unable to initialize due to + [MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail] returns NO.`

here is the code I am using

```
MFMailComposeViewController *controller = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
[controller setMailComposeDelegate:self];
[controller setSubject:subject];
[controller setMessageBody:body isHTML:true];
[controller setToRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObject:address]];
[screenViewController presentViewController:controller
                                   animated:YES
                                 completion:nil];
```

Comment: What makes it Swift?

Comment: my mistake, I edited it

Comment: Where does the thing that you so-call controller come from?

Comment: it's in the first line

Comment: As far as I read your code, I don't find anything wrong, provided that you have the didFinishWithResult delegate method.

Comment: Make sure you have defined a default mail account in settings.